# error C2065 and i have no idea what is wrong

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Admin {

    static void editUser() {
        vector<User> usr = FileManager::createVector();  //errors are here

        ...

    }
};

class FileManager {
public:
    static vector<User> createVector() {
        string name;
        string surname;
        string code;
        float miles;
        float balance;
        vector<User> users; 

        ifstream getUsers("users.txt");

        while (getUsers >> name >> surname >> code >> miles >> balance) {
            User temp(name, surname, code, miles, balance);
            users.push_back(temp);
        }

        return users;
    }
};
```

This is a piece of code I'm writing and I get these 2 errors:

error C2653: 'FileManager' : is not a class or namespace name

error C3861: 'createVector': identifier not found

The thing is I've looked all over the internet and I really can't see what is wrong, my head hurts a lot, and time is limited. I really didn't want to ask here because you probably have more important questions to answer. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Files are processed from the top down.  Your declaration of `FileManager` needs to be visible before you can use it.

Comment: thanks ninja. i guess i'm really tired to think this obvious thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either define `FileManager` before `Admin` class or use [forward declaration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration) to make it visible for compiler.